# How to create view with join in mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Hello I have 2 table on my sql

```
- user,  
- user_right,
```

on user table I have;

```
- login_name
- name,
- surname,
- comapny_code
```

on user_right table I have,

```
- login_name,
- vendor_id,
- is_active,
- access_right_code
```

now what I want to do is I would like to get all entities from 2 tables and join them according to login_Name and after create view called viewExample

Any help would be helpful

Comment: What is the problem? Provide us with Your code and tell us what is not understandable.

Comment: I would like to inner join those two coloumns according to login_name

Comment: Where is Your code? What is the problem? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create a view with the following statement:

```
create view viewExample as select * from user as u join user_right as right on u.login_name = right.login_name
```

Comment: Thank you but I dont want to take all coloumn I would like to take specific coluumn that I wrote above

Comment: simply replace select * with select u.login_name, u.vendor_id, etc.
you can also give them new names for example: u.login_name as userName

Comment: I am sorry I could not figure it out I am very new at Db :)

Comment: select * adds all columns from all tables to your result. If you want to just select certain columns from certain views, you have to specifically name them in your select statement: 
select u.login_name, u.name, right.vendor_id from user as u join user_rights right on u.login_name = right.login_name

Comment: create view userRight as select name, surname, company_code from user as u join user_right as right on u.login_name = right.login_name;                                      where I am going to put vendor_id,
- is_active,
- access_right_code

Comment: you add the needed columns before the from bracket

Comment: create view userRight as select name, surname, company_code, vendor_id, is_active, access_right_code from user as u join user_right as right on u.login_name = right.login_name;                                          like this sir

Answer (score 0):

you could use left join

```
select
user.logintable,
user.name,
user.surname
user.company_code,
user_right.vendor_id,
user_right.is_active,
user_right.access_right_code
from user(
LEFT JOIN `user_right` ON ((user.logintable = user_right.logintable)))
group by user.logintable.
```